# Are AngularJS' dependency injection and RequireJS essentially the same?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I started using AngularJS not long ago and am practice to keep the Controller slim. My understanding of AngularJS' dependency injection is that it makes external JS code available in the controller.

I am also new to RequireJS, for I want to reduce loading time. I have done some reading but I am still confused. My impression is that AngularJS' dependency injection works similarly to RequireJS - loading functions on the fly when I need them.

Am I on the right track or am I completely wrong?

Comment: You may be interested at my take on Angular+Require+Lazy loading, [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are quite different.  [Angular DI involves components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Examples of Angular components are factories, directives, and filters. Angular provides several ways to inject a component into something else, but is not concerned about how to load these components or where they are stored. They could be all stored in a single .js file, in multiple files, or inline in the HTML document. The general assumption is that each component is loaded at page load, but that might not be the case.

[RequireJS is a file and module loader](http://www.requirejs.org/). Each individual module is in it's own file.  RequireJS uses ajax methods to load modules on demand as required.

Where Angular is more concerned with the IOC portion of the DI picture, RequireJS is more focused on file loading, data transfer, and memory conservation portions.

It is possible, and common, to use RequireJS to enhance the DI functionality of Angular, but unless it's a large scale app with hundreds of script files, it's normally not necessary.